# Vlookup but return sheet name if found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Currently, this will return "Yes" (which is in the 6th column) or "Not Found".  Would it be possible to return the sheet name if true?

Thanks in advance.

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1eMzpzOJBDmrJfxqHTqEcllK8lFIN8C8fSkQUpZY1gJM", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("179IscQOWpn7W1GPH5RSK4sc8zxUS2Ll3AoIwkxEPOX4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1Xv0cjLgT_20ETSsWL031ybSvqG3onZlKMYXrLWiR1vc", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1Yjp-AVuuKYMNonUADc37h0CInN9cr7GCnxx0wIwoaY4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1d1rGCzi8W975i__wZ-7RcuXMmWFXYjg5sZTceLDjgRw", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1ve8EAw3OMf_xRofRgRa6vBPGA3P72Gk8E77yrGFXyF8", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("17-NKDd-WCO_XE0zXEwEcZ8CGHrB_cRIHg7wHnMnrIt4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1bI2W5b3-WlgLe401enLpt9hqqjxvD41zMsU2gSGUsaQ", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1Zn75yae3XVhXxQEDLuG3gCZjkce2HDcxUaVDEfJmgck", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"),6,false), "Not Found")))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

if all sheet names are same just use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1eMzpzOJBDmrJfxqHTqEcllK8lFIN8C8fSkQUpZY1gJM", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("179IscQOWpn7W1GPH5RSK4sc8zxUS2Ll3AoIwkxEPOX4", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Xv0cjLgT_20ETSsWL031ybSvqG3onZlKMYXrLWiR1vc", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Yjp-AVuuKYMNonUADc37h0CInN9cr7GCnxx0wIwoaY4", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1d1rGCzi8W975i__wZ-7RcuXMmWFXYjg5sZTceLDjgRw", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1ve8EAw3OMf_xRofRgRa6vBPGA3P72Gk8E77yrGFXyF8", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("17-NKDd-WCO_XE0zXEwEcZ8CGHrB_cRIHg7wHnMnrIt4", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1bI2W5b3-WlgLe401enLpt9hqqjxvD41zMsU2gSGUsaQ", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Zn75yae3XVhXxQEDLuG3gCZjkce2HDcxUaVDEfJmgck", 
 "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "Not Found"))))))))), 
 "Yes", "Current Roster (Master)")
```

---

### update:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1eMzpzOJBDmrJfxqHTqEcllK8lFIN8C8fSkQUpZY1gJM", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "1st"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("179IscQOWpn7W1GPH5RSK4sc8zxUS2Ll3AoIwkxEPOX4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "2nd"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Xv0cjLgT_20ETSsWL031ybSvqG3onZlKMYXrLWiR1vc", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "3rd"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Yjp-AVuuKYMNonUADc37h0CInN9cr7GCnxx0wIwoaY4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "xxx"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1d1rGCzi8W975i__wZ-7RcuXMmWFXYjg5sZTceLDjgRw", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "ccc"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1ve8EAw3OMf_xRofRgRa6vBPGA3P72Gk8E77yrGFXyF8", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "123"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("17-NKDd-WCO_XE0zXEwEcZ8CGHrB_cRIHg7wHnMnrIt4", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "999"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1bI2W5b3-WlgLe401enLpt9hqqjxvD41zMsU2gSGUsaQ", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "9th"),
 IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A2, IMPORTRANGE("1Zn75yae3XVhXxQEDLuG3gCZjkce2HDcxUaVDEfJmgck", "Current Roster (Master)!A2:H"), 6, ), "yes", "♥♥♥"), 
 "Not Found")))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: The sheets all have different names, the tabs are all the same though. I'm trying to pull the sheet name.

Comment: @cpaone in that case the only way is to hardcode it into formula

Comment: I can change "current roster" to unique names if that will make it easier. How would I go about changing the formula if that were the case?

Comment: @cpaone it won't do either. to read (get) spreadsheet name or sheet name you need to use script. in your case you would need such script in every of your spreadsheets you want to import from. but this wont cut it as well coz you cant read with script (nor formula) the scripts from other spreadsheets. see the updated answer

Comment: UPDATE: i didnt capitalize the yes. works now. TY!